# How do I get scrollbar on panel

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Form` with a `Panel`. In this `Panel`, I want to use the vertical `scrollbar` when I needed.

How do I do this? I've tried setting `autoscroll` true and set a min scroll height, but the scrollbar never appears.

I've also tried this:

```
my_panel.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
```

but then I get the error that scrollbar is not a member of `my_panel`?

Thanks.

Comment: Set the AutoScrollMinSize property.  When its Height is larger than the panel's client size then the vertical scrollbar automatically appears.

Answer (score 1):

**[Autoscroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** property is actually enough to achieve your need. Basically a panel with `autoscroll`  property true will display the `scroll bar` only when the `contents/components` inside that `panel` exceeds over its bound. In other words, `Scroll bar` appears with controls which have `autoscroll` property set to true when the particular control's contents are larger than its `visible` area. I think your panel is having some minimum amount of contents/controls which fits inside that panel's bound.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I found on the internet too.... But content is definitely larger than its visible area! But scrollbar never appears! I'm lost!

Comment: @user2989415 Ok, if you are displaying the contents in the form of labels, Then try to figure out whether the `autosize` property of that label is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I know You asked this question more then year ago, but... ;)

Recently, I had same problem (label inside panel, and I need only vertical scrollbar).

If You want only vertical scrollbar of panel with label inside, use code bellow :

```
Dim pnl As New Panel
pnl.Size = New Size(300, 200)
pnl.AutoSize = True
Dim lbl As New Label
lbl.Location = New Point(0, 0)
lbl.AutoSize = True
lbl.MaximumSize = New Size(pnl.Width - 18, 0)
'18 is approx. width of scroller, and height must be zero.
'even if Label is set to AutoSize, MaximumSize will not allow him to
'expand more then set width. 
'Height of zero px will allow Label to expand as much as he need
pnl.Controls.Add(lbl)
Me.Controls.Add(pnl)
```

I hope this code help You.

btw. sorry for my weak English, I hope You will understand ;) :)